# Move files from one directory to another. But, rename files before the move if the destination directory already contains file of same name?

Tags: ls, rename, mv

I need to move all the text files from /abc/d1 to /abc/d2, 
but files need to be renamed if /abc/d2 has files with the same name already.

```
cd /abc/d1

mv *txt /abc/d2
```

Answer (score 2):

[rsync](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) can do this with the **`--backup`** flag, but it renames the preexisting file in the target location. You can specify how it renames with further options.

> **-b, --backup**
> With this option, preexisting destination files are renamed as each file is transferred or deleted. You can control where the backup file goes and what (if any) suffix gets appended using the **--backup-dir** and **--suffix** options.

Make sure you thoroughly review the options and flags of `rsync` to ensure you don't clobber or delete any important files/data.